# Library for OpenStreetMap offline rendering and routing

Tags: openstreetmap, offline

I found libosmscout library for OpenStreetMap offline rendering and routing in Github and trying to build iOS demo, but it has lots of issues that I can't solve myself and there is no sufficient guide.
Is there anyone who had experience in building this library?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to explain your problems.

Comment: I finally run and show offline map on my simulator. Thanks for your quick update, Vlad

Comment: Thanks for your interest, @scai there was a problem in library, but Vlad updated it rapidly and I can finally run it